# 'async'/'await' in Node.js is not working in Node.js v8.1.0

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to flush the Redis cache database and return the status in the response. But before the cache is cleared it returns the response.

In the below code the *console.log()* call will always print undefined since flushRedisDB is not awaited.

My Node.js version is v8.1.0

#### File *myfile.js*

```
async function flushRedisapi(request, response)
{
    try {
        var value = await redisModules.flushRedisDB();
        console.log("the value is: " + value);
        if(value)
            response.status(200).send({status : 'Redis Cache Cleared'});
        else
            response.status(400).send({status : "Redis Cache could not be flushed"});

    } catch (error) {
        response.status(400).send({status : "Redis Cache could not be flushed"});
    }
}
```

#### File *redismodule.js*

```
var redisClient;        // Global (avoids duplicate connections)

module.exports =
{
    openRedisConnection : function()
    {
        if (redisClient == null)
        {
            redisClient = require("redis").createClient(6379, 'localhost');
            redisClient.selected_db = 1;
        }
    },
    isRedisConnectionOpened : function()
    {
        if (redisClient && redisClient.connected == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(redisClient)
                redisClient.end();  // End and open once more

            module.exports.openRedisConnection();

            return true;
        }
    },
    flushRedisDB: async function()
    {
        if(!module.exports.isRedisConnectionOpened())
            return false;

        await redisClient.flushall(function (err, result)
        {
            return (result == 'OK') ? true : false;
        });
    }
};
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can't use `await` with node style callbacks. It only works with promises.

Comment: can you help me in converting flushRedisDB function to use promises concept so that it works.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko await redisClient.flushall should wait right ?

Comment: not that simple unless it returns a promise :). Check my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Async/await only works with promises (as said in the comment). So just wrap your callback into a Promise.

```
function cbToPromise(asyncFunc, ...params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asyncFunc(...params, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
};

try {
    const result = await cbToPromise(redisClient.flushall);
    return result == 'OK';
}
catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

**Addendum:**

It will work only if the signature of the callback is `function(err, result)`. Which, according to the other answer, would not be the case (no error passed as first parameter), as it never fail. So in this case just strip the err parameter, reject, and try/catch handler.

I let my answer in place here for convenience because it will most probably help you solve it for other Redis related methods.

Comment: Note that in some cases you may have to bind the function to the object that it's attached to, if it relies on its context, ie. `cbToPromise(redisClient.flushall.bind(redisClient));`

Answer (score 6):

`async/await` only works with promises so this code doesn't wait for a callback

```
await redisClient.flushall(function (err, result)
{
    return (result == 'OK') ? true : false;
});
```

You need to promisify the `flushall` method. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/bnoguchi/redis-node#clientflushallcallback) it always succeed.

```
const flushall = () => new Promise(resolve => redisClient.flushall(resolve))

const flushed = await flusall()
```

BTW. There is `util.promisify` function built-in in Node.js version 8 and later that allows to promisify Node.js style [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) functions. But it won't handle always succeeding function like this, so you'd need to provide a custom implementation for it to work. About [`util.promisify`](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html#custom-promisified-functions).

Comment: may be in another scenarios what if there is both error and success ?

Comment: @Sharath If I understand you correctly then `util.promisify` should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) offers its own promisification which will [promisify all Redis functions](http://redis.js.org/#redis-a-nodejs-redis-client-usage-example-promises) allowing you to just append `Async` to any Redis command you wish to use. In your case, it would look like `flushallAsync`.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
```

Once promisified you can use async / await to your heart's content.